# How to extract values from maps inside a list?

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart

I have a list containing quotes but the list contains map. How should I access the values of author and text from the list given below.

```
List quotes = [
      {
        "author": "Abraham Lincoln",
        "text": "A house divided against itself cannot stand."
      },
      {
        "author": "Abraham Lincoln",
        "text": "Important principles may, and must, be inflexible."
      },
      {
        "author": "Abraham Lincoln",
        "text": "I destroy my enemies when I make them my friends."
      },
      {
        "author": "Abraham Lincoln",
        "text":
            "You have to do your own growing no matter how tall your grandfather was."
      }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values in a very simple way:

```
quotes[index]["text"] 
quotes[index]["author"]
```

Here `index` will be an integer like 0,1,2.. as it is telling the list which map it has to access.

If you still don't understand

```
quotes[0]["text"]
```

will give you the first quote viz- "A house divided against itself cannot stand."